# Azure App and Services and IdentityServer4

Tags: azure, identityserver4

I have a situation where I have a React Web App and two REST services using Identity4 Server.

Problem is that these work well locally in my Workstation but if I deploy these three parts into Azure they will not work.

I have Azure SQL Database containing all Databases and tables it needs. Locally I use my local Database. So, Database is not the problem. It's deployed in same way with Azures manner.

My question is that how should I configure a React Web App using Identity4 Server with REST services?

I thing that Azure needs some kind of proper configuration but dont't know what.

I also have read Identity4 Server's documention pages but haven't found anything there that would help mr installing it into Azure.

Can anyone help me with this issue? thanks

Br

Mike

Comment: Have you got any logs/error messages? It will be hard to help without that.

Answer (score -1):

One error is HTTP 401 Unauthorized error